# ZoneDateTime.getTimeZone() is not what I've set

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

I want to return the current server time, including the time zone set.
Currently I'm doing it like this.

```
  private void handleGetTimeDate(User_Itf user, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServiceException {
    JSONObject time = new JSONObject();
    time.put("hour", ZonedDateTime.now().getHour());
    time.put("minute", ZonedDateTime.now().getMinute());
    time.put("second", ZonedDateTime.now().getSecond());
    time.put("year", ZonedDateTime.now().getYear());
    time.put("month", ZonedDateTime.now().getMonthValue());
    time.put("day", ZonedDateTime.now().getDayOfMonth());
    time.put("zone", Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID());
    response.getWriter().print(time);
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }
```

In a different method I set the servers time zone successfully with `timedatectl -setTimezone`. I've even started doing `Calendar.getInstance().setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(dateString));` while setting the timezone, in hope, it would update the Calendar. After I changed the time zone, the handleGetTimeDate method still returns the old TimeZone and time with the now wrong offset.
Sometime all the sudden, the method returns the actual set timezone, but I couldn't figure out the behaviour yet. 
does anyone have some ideas on how I could solve this problem, and always get the actual set timezone?

**Update**

That's the result from the terminal:

```
root@dev-ru1:~# timedatectl
      Local time: Wed 2017-06-07 21:26:55 ART
  Universal time: Thu 2017-06-08 00:26:55 UTC
        RTC time: Thu 2017-06-08 00:26:51
       Time zone: America/Argentina/Tucuman (ART, -0300)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a
```

And this is why I get from my Java method:

```
 {"hour":21,"month":6,"year":2017,"zone":"America/Belem","day":7,"minute":30,"second":35}
```

Comment: Note: you should put the value of `ZonedDateTime.now()` in a variable, in order that you use a consistent value on each of the `time.put` lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Tomcat-Server (version 8.0.x) apparently catches the TimeZone setting. This means that Tomcat itself only will update the setting on a reboot.

If you want to change the TimeZone without a reboot, you need to manually set the new time zone in the tomcat enviroment.

This can be done this way:
`TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(dateString));`

Comment: That's not Tomcat, it's the Java Runtime Library. To get the timezone, use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` (that's what `ZonedDateTime` uses too). `systemDefault()` internally uses the old `TimeZone.getDefault()`, and it caches the value the first time it's used. You don't have to reboot the server, just restart Tomcat, i.e. restart the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid calling `ZonedDateTime.now()` so many times (for performance but more importantly consistency reasons: imagine that you run the method just before midnight and the hour is seen as 23 but by the time you read the day, it is past midnight).

Also, there is no need to mix the java time API with the legacy Calendar class.

```
private void handleGetTimeDate(User_Itf user, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServiceException {
  JSONObject time = new JSONObject();

  ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
  time.put("hour", now.getHour());
  time.put("minute", now.getMinute());
  time.put("second", now.getSecond());
  time.put("year", now.getYear());
  time.put("month", now.getMonthValue());
  time.put("day", now.getDayOfMonth());
  time.put("zone", now.getZone());

  response.getWriter().print(time);
  response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
}
```

Note that `ZonedDateTime.now()` uses the system time zone, [which should change if you update it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault--):

> If the system default time-zone is changed, then the result of this method will also change.

Comment: You probably need `getZone().getId()`.

Comment: If a different timezone is required, add `.withZoneSameInstant(zoneId)` after the `.now()`, with `zoneId` representing the desired (non-default) zone.

Comment: Well I avoided the repeated call of `ZoneDateTime.now()` but I still get the same result. I updated my question with it.
@Andreas the `zoneId` is accually what I want to know :)

Comment: I just figured something out. I'm working on a tomcat stack.
could it be that the tomcat server is only taking the new time zone on a restart? Right now, it looks this way...

Comment: @HerrDerb That's very possible.

Comment: @HerrDerb Correct, except it's the JVM, not Tomcat.